# Standard ML : Check conditions when iterating a list

Tags: functional-programming, sml

i'm studying the programming language Standard ML and i am wondering how i can iterate a list with a check condition.

In other languages we have for loops like :

```
var input;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if(arr[i] == input) {
      //you have arrived at your condition...
   } else {
     //other case
   }
}
```

f.ex

i want to iterate through a list and check if the input variable matches a existing element in the list.

```
i = 5  
xs = [1,5,2,3,6] --> the element matches after one iteration.

fun check i nil = []
| check i (x::xs) = if i=x 
                    then //dowork 
                    else //iterate;
```

I've gone through many documentations on how to implement this without success.

It would be really helpful if someone could give me some explaining regarding how i can use `let val A in B end;` inside or outside of if conditions for this kind of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how i can iterate a list with a check condition
>
> ```
> fun check i nil = []
> | check i (x::xs) = if i=x 
>                     then //dowork 
>                     else //iterate;
> ```
>
> i want to iterate through a list and check if the input variable matches a existing element in the list.

I would call this a predicate combinator. It already exists in the standard library and is called `List.exists`. But you can also make it yourself:

```
fun exists p [] = false
  | exists p (x::xs) = p x orelse exists p xs
```

This is a simplification of the if-then-else you're attempting, which would look like:

```
fun exists p [] = false
  | exists p (x::xs) = if p x then true else exists p xs
```

If-then-else isn't really necessary when the result type is a boolean, since `orelse`, `andalso` and `not` are short-circuiting (will not evaluate their second operand if the result can be determined with the first).

Using this `List.exists` function to check if a list contains a specific element, you have to construct a `p` that compares the list element with some given value, e.g.:

```
fun check y xs = List.exists (fn x => ...) xs
```

This may seem a bit more complicated than simply writing `check` recursively from scratch,

```
fun check y [] = false
  | check y (x::xs) = ... orelse check y xs
```

but a solution using higher-order functions is preferred for several reasons.

One is that a seasoned reader will quickly detect what you're doing when seeing `List.exists`: Ah, you're scanning a list for an element given a predicate. Whereas if your function is explicitly recursive, the reader will have to read the entire recursion scheme: OK, the function doesn't do anything funky, which I'd have known if I'd seen e.g. `List.exists`.